# Sum a CSV column while ignoring headers in between in python

Tags: python

I work with huge datasets and sometimes it requires me to sum and subtract columns which have numbers. I was able to come up with a code which could do the work for me. Let's take the below example:

```
id,flag_s,amount
1,A,10
2,B,20
3,A,30
```

The below code would subtract the 'amount' field if it found a 'B' in the flag_s field:

```
import csv
with open("MOCK_DATA with text qualifier.csv","r+",encoding='utf8') as fin:
    headerline = fin.readline()

flag = None
debit = 0
value = 0
for row in csv.reader(fin,delimiter=","):

    value =row[2].strip()
    value = float(row[2]) if value else 0.0
    flag = row[1].strip()
    if flag == "B":
        debit-=value
    else:
        debit+=value
print (debit)
```

Now the problem which i am facing is: There are times when there are multiple CSV files. We usually need to append them and then run the codes on them. Lets say I get a csv file A and then I have a csv file B; I would need to append both the files and then run the sum code. If we take the below example:

```
id,flag_s,amount
1,A,10
2,B,20
3,A,30
id,flag_s,amount
4,B,10
5,A,10
6,B,10
```

Python is throwing the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sum_csv1_v4_SAP.py", line 11, in <module>
    value = float(row[2]) if value else 0.0
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'amount'
```

Is there a walk around this problem?

Comment: You said "_We usually need to append them_" - I'd try to do this without the header, so that the cause of the problem is addressed. We don't see the regarding code here, but it should be possible to add sth like _if append to existing data: then append only data rows / skip header row_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this code works for your use case.

```
import csv
with open("MOCK_DATA with text qualifier.csv","r+",encoding='utf8') as fin:
    headerline = fin.readline()

    flag = None
    debit = 0
    value = 0
    for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=","):

        try:
            value = float(row[2].strip())
        except ValueError:
            value = 0.0

        flag = row[1].strip()
        if flag == "B":
            debit-=value
        else:
            debit+=value
    print (debit)
```

Comment: The `value = 0.0` in the `except` branch is a _very bad_ statement. If a value does not exist, you should _not_ assume that it equals to 0.

Comment: Actually if there are no values in the data, we consider it '0.00'. Kind of that's the way we work. If it should have a value we would get back to the client but by default we consider it '0.00'

Comment: But do you consider tje extra headers as 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should use  the `try/except` statement:

```
try:
    value = float(row[2]) if value else 0.0
except ValueError: # A header, perhaps
    continue       # Skip the row
```